# python programming for geospatial development

Tags: python, shapefile

I am new in python programming for geospatial development. I want to create an app to allow users to click on a shapefile to get the data associated with that clicked point.

Which python libraries can I use?

and another suggestions to start in python programming for geospatial development?

Comment: There's many way to access and manipulate spatial objects : [link]https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/ [link]http://geopandas.org/  [link]https://www.gislounge.com/learning-programming-for-gis/

Comment: any suggestion to start?

Comment: Maybe you can just do this with a skinning of QGIS. Do you want a web app or a desktop app or something else? What you do is up to you. However gis.SE lends towards answering specific questions (rather than broad "give me options", which don't really have a single right answer). I'd suggest trying something that might work for you, then coming back with a specific question. Check the Tour too - see help.

Comment: @BradHards I want to create a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

GeoPandas is a pretty complete library, that can handle most of what you are asking.

It has good documentation and examples.